# "set iskeyword-=_" not being set from vimrc

Tags: vim, config, autocmd

Basically the title. When I include in my vimrc

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

and save it, when I reload gvim and type

```
:set iskeyword
```

I still see

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

As you can see, the '_' is still there. If I just `:set iskeyword-=_` it works as intended. Why doesn't this work from my vimrc? Is there an alternate way I can get around this and if so how?

Comment: Is it *your* vimrc or the default vimrc that you are not supposed to touch?

Answer (score 12):

Check with `:verbose set iskeyword?` where this got set. Note that many filetype plugins change this value (but for a no-argument, plain Vim launch with an empty buffer, none should have been set).

If `:verbose` doesn't yield the answer, capture a full log of the Vim startup with `vim -V20vimlog`, and search for the option.

Also, is your `.vimrc` actually sourced? `:scriptnames` tells you.

Comment: My _vimrc is sourced, and it looks like it was last set from ~\vim\vim74\autoload\netrw.vim. This seems to change though. How do I see what the options are for `vim -V20vimlog`?

Comment: After quitting Vim, you should have a file `vimlog` in your current directory. It contains all commands executed during the Vim session. Search for `iskeyword` (or `isk`) in there.

Comment: The only instance of `isk` or `iskeyword` that I see in the log is where it sources my `_vimrc`. I even added an extra line (`set iskeyworkd+=/)` to see if it picked up on it (which it did) but it still doesn't look like it changed when I check with `set iskeyword`.

Comment: Do you use sessions? Is something in your `.viminfo` that sets this?

Comment: I don't know about my `.viminfo` but in my config file I do have this:
`" Persistent Undo ~ Not sure if this works
" Keep undo history across sessions, by storing in file
if has('persistent_undo')
  silent !mkdir ~/.vim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
  set undodir=~/.vim/backups
  set undofile
endif`

That's the only thing regarding sessions in my config

Comment: Found out my `iskeyword-=-` gets overwritten from various ftplugins (tried it with .vim and .slim files and both ftplugins overwrite it).

Is there a way to set `iskeyword` globally, so it takes precedence over any ftplugin?

Comment: @cseelus No; either turn off ftplugins completely, or undo via the after directory, as per ThomasH's answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Overriding Global Plugin Settings from .vimrc

I had the same problem with settings coming from a global file type plugin (*perl.vim* in my case) where I wanted to change the *iskeyword* configuration in my .vimrc. Thanks to the hints in other answers I realized that the plugins are evaluated **after** my .vimrc, overriding changes I made.

The [canonical answer](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.3) to this situation is to create an *"after"* directory in your local configuration, like

`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`

and put the `set iskeyword-=_` there. That solved it for me.

Comment: Why are core config options hidden down here where you can't override them in the .vimrc?  R is hiding their damaging config options that break code here, where you need experience in low level core vim hacking to fix.  Adding config options to ftplugin fixed it, why are things unrelated to ftp put here?  Is this systematic obfuscation?  What's next?  Default config options that spins the viewpane upside down so you have to edit .so objects in C and recompile from src to fix?  This is insane.  it's like buying a car and having to rewire the radio so the gas pedal doesn't honk the horn.

Answer (score 2):

Just reset the option in your .vimrc after plugins. According the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html) you can do it like this.

> set iskeyword=@,48-57,192-255

@ - stands for all alphabetic letters 
48-57 - stands for ASCII characters 48 to 57, which are the numbers 0-9 
192-255 - are the printable latin characters

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Found it: in my _vimrc, at the bottom there was two other files getting sourced. I just removed them and it worked!

Comment: i was able to solve it by just putting it towards the end of my .vimrc

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with a `.conf` file. So I did this in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.conf set isk-=.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment in `vim80/ftplugin/perl.vim` it says:

```
" The following line changes a global variable but is necessary to make
" gf and similar commands work.  The change to iskeyword was incorrect.
" Thanks to Andrew Pimlott for pointing out the problem. If this causes a
" problem for you, add an after/ftplugin/perl.vim file that contains
"       set isfname-=:
set isfname+=:
set iskeyword+=:
```

This speaks of changing back `isfname`, but obviously `set iskeyword-=_` can be added in that file (as well).